# How to pass a string from LINQ query to ViewBag

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I am trying to dynamically generate a title for my page. I'm using this query to select an item type:

```
ViewBag.itemType = From row In db.tblCategories
                   Where row.Item_Type_Identifier = itemType
                   Select CStr(row.Item_Type)
                   Distinct
```

And in my view I'm trying to display it like so:

```
<h2>Details for @ViewBag.itemType </h2>
```

Instead of my view displaying the value retrieved from the query I am seeing the LINQ query actually being displayed like so:

```
SELECT [Distinct1].[Item_Type] AS [Item_Type] 
FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT [Extent1].[Item_Type] 
AS [Item_Type] FROM [dbo].[tblCategories] AS [Extent1] 
WHERE [Extent1].[Item_Type_Identifier] = @p__linq__0 ) 
AS [Distinct1]
```

I've attempted to place the value from the query in a variable, and then add that variable to `ViewData` and then retrieve that value in the view.

I've attempted to use `.ToString` on my LINQ instead of casting `CStr`.

Why is my query being placed in my `ViewBag` instead of the value my LINQ returns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because you pass the LINQ query (i.e. IQueriable in this case).

Try something like this:

```
ViewBag.itemType = (From row In db.tblCategories
                   Where row.Item_Type_Identifier = itemType
                   Select CStr(row.Item_Type)
                   Distinct).Single()
```

**(in case if this syntax allowed in VB.NET)**

Comment: He could end up with an error with that syntax like a "Sequence contains more than one element"

Comment: I think `Distinct` doesn't allow that.